# Search and filter records and display in the list box, with more than 10 columns in excel using form and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a programmer or an excel regular user. Just wanted to do Search and display records using one criteria in excel using user Form. My worksheet has 17 columns and I want to search and display records in the list box with selected columns in it. Like 1 : 10 and rest 11 : 17 in the new user form2 text columns which will be popup when I double click on a record in the list box.

I had found some codes on the net which I am using right now, but it allows me to use only 10 columns, when I add 11th column it gives me a error for the code `ListBox2.List(liste, 10) = isim.Offset(0, 10)`

I heard of array, but I am not sure how to use it in my code.

Comment: We can better help you if editing your code and show us the code working for 10 columns. In this way we can use the range you use and show you how to proceed. At leased, does the 17 columns range start with A:A column? So, do you have two lists and want loading them with **selected columns**, or first 10 in the first list and the rest (11:17) in the second one? If you need to load only 10 columns it is possible by iteration, too, even it needs iteration and  a more complicated code. You also are talking about a double click to do something... Please, try clarifying the issues I asked about.

Comment: Do you want loading all 17 columns, but only 10 of them to be displayed in the list box?

Comment: Thank you for replaying to my queries. Yes I want to load all 17 columns and display only 10 in the list box and rest when I double click  on the listed record. A new popup user form will appear with those remaining 7 columns, displayed in text box format. Initially when all records are displayed in the list box with all the columns, it works fine. the movement I search the record the list box display only 10 columns and when I double click on the record it gives me error. I can add the worksheet if you want to go through. Please let me know and how to do that. I am new to the forum.

Comment: If you can share the workbook it would be better. I do not have to imagine such a sheet to test the code I intend providing. You can share it editing your question, or using a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free one, easy to be used...

Comment: How to share or attach a workbook? or I can email it to you if you can give me your ID.

Comment: I have just explained that... Do you know what a transfer site is? If not, click the link on my above comment, then click where it is written to click, browse your computer, select your workbook and press "Open", then "Upload". Wait until a link is provided. Copy it and place it in your next comment...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/j3amrh

Comment: Hope you got it.

Comment: Your code runs correctly in my case. I mean, when double click on a line of `lisbox2`, the second `UserForm` is launched with values from the invisible columns of it loaded in the necessary text boxes... Is it something I am missing from your question? **What error do you receive**?

Comment: The form does not show only 10  columns, but if this is your problem, it can be easily solved...

Comment: Still alive? Didn't you find some time to read my comments and also to test the adapted code I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Please, modify the code in this way:

In order to make the list box showing only 10 columns, use this adapted code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim say As Long
 Sheets("Data").Activate
    say = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Range("b:b"))
      ListBox2.RowSource = "Data!b3:r" & say
      ListBox2.ColumnCount = 17
      ListBox2.ColumnWidths = "120;120;60;50;40;40;30;40;40;40;0;0;0;0;0;70;60"
End Sub
```

In order to place from the 11th column, take care that the list box index starts from 0. Please, use the next code:

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Load UserForm2
 With UserForm2
    .TextBox1 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 10)
    .TextBox2 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 11)
    .TextBox3 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 12)
    .TextBox4 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 13)
    .TextBox5 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 14)
    .TextBox10 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 15)

    .Show
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Fane,      Sorry for the delay in respond. I had gone out. I tried your code didn't work. I just copy pasted. There was my mistake in my initial post instead to 12 I mention 10 columns in the list box. It's 10+2 last 2 columns from the worksheet should be displayed, even with the search and list function. I think the first paragraph 'Private Sub cmdbul1_Click()' should be modified to list 12 columns or all, Like 'Form_Initialize()' display's the records. I may be wrong. Could you please run and check where it goes wrong. Many Thanks.

Comment: Hi Fane,     I am a dummy in VBA, just trying to learn. My first form screen works fine. it displays the records as I want. even in the pop Form2. The problems comes when I search records typing the switch name, it displays the correct records, but only 10 columns, where I want just like first ListBox columns 1:10and 16,17 i:e Port config & remarks. If I am able to display that, then I hope everything else will be fine.

Comment: My humble request  if you can run the form and type any name of the switch display in the list below to search and display in the list box and double click on the displayed record you will come to know where it is getting stuck. It just not allowing me to display records columns more then 10 after search. I want that search should pull all the columns and display only 12 and rest five columns data of the particular double clicked record will be displayed in form2 (popup).

Comment: @Fran: Is it something mentioned in your question about the issues you are asking now and I missed it? You must only stick to the question...

Comment: My question is still the same, but I am not able to explain to correctly. In my initial post I mention 10 columns instead 12. The initial list box which displays all the records along with ''port config. & Remark' is fine. that's how I wanted. When I search particular Switch name record, it displays only 10 columns here I want 12 columns & when I double click it gives me error.  I am extremely very sorry. I have omitted some codes from that file because of error. I'll send it again.

Comment: Please check this workbook, I have put those code in it now.     https://easyupload.io/man378